# Apache Ignite: Received incoming connection from remote node while connecting to this node, rejecting

Tags: java, ignite

There is Ignite configuration with one server and multiple clients. For some reasong one of the clients starts reconnecting to the server frequently and infinitely:

```
[08:10:22,396][INFO][grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-2-#50][TcpCommunicationSpi] Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/192.168.16.6:47100, rmtAddr=/192.168.1.82:51194]
[08:10:22,396][INFO][grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-2-#50][TcpCommunicationSpi] Received incoming connection from remote node while connecting to this node, rejecting [locNode=e5ddba00-0876-4733-8fd8-9a92e129ff43, locNodeOrder=1, rmtNode=9d068a9e-e6bd-4411-b969-8d12d9e0726f, rmtNodeOrder=30]
[08:10:22,599][INFO][grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3-#51][TcpCommunicationSpi] Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/192.168.16.6:47100, rmtAddr=/192.168.1.82:51195]
[08:10:22,599][INFO][grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-3-#51][TcpCommunicationSpi] Received incoming connection from remote node while connecting to this node, rejecting [locNode=e5ddba00-0876-4733-8fd8-9a92e129ff43, locNodeOrder=1, rmtNode=9d068a9e-e6bd-4411-b969-8d12d9e0726f, rmtNodeOrder=30]
```

Looks like this node tries to establish a connection every 200ms, occupying all the workers' threads.

This hangs the server until the problematic node is killed manually. How to stop the node from entering this state?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like  that 192.168.1.82 is not accessible from 192.168.16.6. check your network/firewall settings.

Comment: I don't think so: I can access both 192.168.1.82 and 192.168.16.6 remotely, the server(192.168.16.6) sees 92.168.1.82 and it knows that 92.168.1.82 is trying to reconnect, but it reconnects too fastly.
In any case, it is a strange situation, when a client can hang the server.

Comment: Have you any timeouts in the configuration?

Comment: TcpDiscoverySpi.SocketTimeout = 3 sec
TcpCommunicationSpi.MessageQueueLimit = 1
ICompute.Timeout = 5sec
This is all the limits I have